# Eventbrite tags

Tags: api, tags, eventbrite

The EventBrite API is great but there are a couple of really simple features that would make it much better. In particular, does anyone know a way to update the tags property of an event (or set it on a new event) - I can't see it on the API method http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_update/ but'tags' is available in the response from get_event so am I just missing something.

If this just hasn't been exposed through event_update yet it would be fantastic to get that implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. Eventbrite's event data used to be organized around 'tags' -- users could tag any events for search and discovery.

This functionality was available through our web platform and the API, but has since been removed. So, no matter how users are creating new events (web or API), we've removed the ability to add tags.

The event_get method (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/) still exposes the tag information when it's available ... and for specific (less interesting) legacy reasons, there are still a fair amount of events that will continue to have this tag data, so we'll continue to support it in our read API.

If you're using the tag feature for organizing your own events, some of our users will actually put the tag information in the event descriptions as HTML comments using /event_update. This might not meet your use-case, but some people have hacked it to meet their needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Out of interest, why was tagging removed?