# How to get Event Photos using Eventbrite API?

Tags: android, events, eventbrite

I am using Eventbrite APIs for my Android application based on Event.

I want to get photos related to that event , I am unable to find that from API documentation https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/.

Also I want Artist list of that event. Does it possible ?
Please help me. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU You can upload image which is a logo [e.g.] at the time of Event creation only.

To pull the image, you need to have an `id` which can give you image object back.

Below links may help you :

1] https://www.eventbrite.com/create#

2] https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/formats/image/

3] https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/media/#ebapi-get-media-id

4] https://www.eventbrite.com/support/articles/en_US/How_To/how-to-add-images-to-an-event-description?lg=en_US

5] https://www.eventbrite.com/support/articles/en_US/How_To/how-to-add-images-to-an-event-listing?lg=en_US

Comment: Thank you for your replay @VVB

But I want images which tagged in event  as we are tag that event in any photo then does that photo consider as event photos?

Comment: Tag feature is no more accessible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380228/eventbrite-tags

Comment: Does i get venue's photos where event held ? not that one venue pic but taken photos of that location @VVB

Comment: Please ask questions separately.

Comment: this also consider in this post no need to ask separately.